# asp net core export to Excel

Tags: excel, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm not sure that this kind of question can be posted here, but I think that it might be interested to many programmers. I need a package that would provide me with an interface for creating Excel files. I looked up on nuget and found several packages, but not a single one that supports asp net core.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Please find [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK).**

I'm using v2.5 with ASP.NET Core + .NET4.6, but as far I know the latest version v2.7 has added support for .NET Standard 1.3 - please read the [change log](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK#change-log).

**More info:**

- [Where to get the NuGet package](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK#the-latest-builds)
- [Documentation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK#documentation)
- [Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)
- [Official releases of the NuGet packages for the Open XML SDK](https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/open-xml-sdk)

Answer (score 14):

Little bit of thread necromancy here; however I wanted to share some other options that I found for any of the other search explorers out there.

### [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki)

- Uses AlphaNumeric Cell navigation e.g. `ws.Cell("B2").Value = "Contacts";`
- Has a large amount of documentation and How To's
- This is only for excel spreadsheets and does not have support for other Microsoft file types.
- To install use PM> Install-Package ClosedXML

### [NPOI](https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI)

- Uses Numeric Cell navigation e.g.

  `var rowIndex = 0;
  IRow row = sheet1.CreateRow(rowIndex);
  row.Height = 30 * 80;
  row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("this is content");`
- Supports read/write for  xls, doc, ppt files.
- To install use nuget: Install-Package DotNetCore.NPOI

### [EPPlus.Core](https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core)

- This is an unofficial port of the [EPPlus Library](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki) to .NET Core.

***somewhat relevant:***

### [Datatables.net](https://datatables.net/)

> I need a package that would provide me with an interface for creating Excel files.

I am not certain if you are displaying this data and are looking for a way to export it to excel but this *could* be an option as well if you are attempting to allow this in either an admin or public view. There are options available for customizing the output via a callback if the default output is undesirable.

- [DOM Structure documentation](https://editor.datatables.net/manual/styling/dom)
- [Export Buttons](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/exportButtons)
- [Excluding Specific Columns](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/columns.html)
- [Customization of Excel Export](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5)

Answer (score 1):

GrapeCity Document API for Excel supports .NET core 2.0+ (cross platform) very well, and you can try: https://www.grapecity.com/documents-api-excel

API is VSTO style and pretty straightforward:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
```